# Close as duplicate loop

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions

[usb write protected!](https://superuser.com/questions/148385/usb-write-protected) is closed as a duplicate of

https://superuser.com/questions/112401/why-would-disks-mysteriously-become-write-protected which is closed as a duplicate of

[Remove the write protection from a USB flash disk](https://superuser.com/questions/158083/how-to-remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk) which is closed as a duplicate of the first question,

[usb write protected!](https://superuser.com/questions/148385/usb-write-protected). Funnily enough, these questions were all closed by [random ♦](https://superuser.com/users/307/random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could have sworn that one of them was being left open as the canonical resource on this strange flipping.

Since [Remove the write protection from an USB disk](https://superuser.com/questions/158083/remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk) has two answers, and mentions more of what could happen along with the remedy, it's re-opened.

Comment: While you're at it, mind editing http://superuser.com/questions/148385/usb-write-protected to point directly to http://superuser.com/questions/158083/remove-the-write-protection-from-an-usb-flash-disk instead of having to go through two links? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, edited for the link, and we're at status-completed now. @hel